# jQuery Bind 'Change' to Range of Fields in Multiple Groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 tabs. In each tab, there's there's a separate form with multiple sections of fields. Fields are bootstrap radio or checkbox button groups.

Each section can have any number of fields.

What I am trying to accomplish is to use jQuery to bind('change') to the last few fields of each section, so that only when the last few fields of the section is completed, the next section is shown.

I'm currently binding to all fields in each section, so when user changes even just the first field in current section, the next section is shown. I'd like to change that to only when last or second to last fields are completed then the next section is shown.

General code structure example:https://jsfiddle.net/uqvhw7sb/4/

Basic Example:

```
<tab1>
<formA>
<groupA>
<input a[]>
<input a[]>
<input a[]>

<input b[]>
<input b[]>
<input b[]>

<input c[]>
<input c[]>
<input c[]>
</groupA>

<groupB>
<input d[]>
<input d[]>
<input d[]>

<input e[]>
<input e[]>
<input e[]>

<input f[]>
<input f[]>
<input f[]>
</groupB>
</formA>
</tab1>

<tab2>
Same kind of thing, possible same field names
</tab2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`slice(-2)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to filter last 2 elements in a collection. So loop through all your groups and look for input collection within that group and filter that collection

Something like:

```
$(".fgroups").each(function(){
    var $group = $(this);
    $group.find('input:checkbox').slice(-2).on("change", function() {
        $group.next().toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this is only triggering when one of the last two inputs from the last checkbox group is changed. So, if I click on c[0] using the example above, nothing happens. Clicking c[1] or c[2] works. Also, can you explain the toggle(this.checked)? Not sure why that's there. I replaced with removeClass() in my test.

Comment: I followed what you said...last 2 in each section...you weren't specific what constituted a section. If you want last 2 in each button group change first selector to match those

Comment: It is a bit confusing with the wording I admit... being that there's groups of fields (sections) and groups of fields (checkbox values). Your example is clean and close but not fully accurate for the problem though. It did however lead me to a solution that is working well. Not sure what to do here....